# Jest sharing a set of tests for external API

Tags: typescript, api, testing, jestjs

Our company has a piece of software that provides a public API that we are looking to test.  This software is not written in Typescript, or another front end language.  What we are looking to do though, is test the public API endpoints.

For instance, the API endpoint might have the following routes:

```
POST   /rest/user/login
GET    /rest/user/
GET    /rest/product/:product_id
PUT    /rest/product/:product_id
DELETE /rest/product/:product_id
```

We have created a large number of tests, using Typescript and Jest for testing our API.  However, there are some common things that we want to test on all the routes.  For instance, we might be looking to validate that the Content-Type header field is set properly for different routes (some might be XML, others JSON).

I have found that we continually copy the same test() block into each `*.spec.ts` file.  If we make a change and add a header file, then we need to change dozens of files to ensure the proper routes have this check.

I want to be able to make a common method, a simple typescript function, that will then accept parameters (the route, http method, etc.) and then perform the validations.

My question however, is the best way to implement this, as I might have a common `transaction-common-headers.ts` file with the tests.  I am looking though to be able to have a beforeEach() section, as well as the actual tests it('should ...') which will then be executed.

In my normal test files (`*.spec.ts`) I have used functions before to share code, but I am not sure if this can simply be done with full tests?

Can I have 1 test file (`transaction-id.spec.ts`), then include the common `transaction-common-headers.ts` file with the tests, which might have their own describe, beforeEach, it() methods?

If so, how do I import that, or add that into the `transaction-id.spec.ts` file?

Ideally, the `transaction-common-headers.ts` file would be something like:

```
describe('validate the required transaction header fields are on the request', () => {
    let Headers: Map<string, string>;
    beforeEach( () => {
        Headers = new Map<string, string>([
            ['X-Transaction-Id', 'abcdefg'],
            ['X-Transaction-Date', '2023-05-31'],
            ['X-Transaction-Service', 'xyz'],
        ]);
        ... // Additional Setup     
    });

    it.each([
        ['X-Transaction-Id'],
        ['X-Transaction-Date'],
        ['X-Transaction-Service'],
    ])('should have status code 400 when header field {%s} is not present', async (HeaderField: string) => {
        Headers.delete(HeaderField);
        
        const Fetch$ = await FetchExternalAPIData('/rest/product/ABC123DEF', 'post', Headers);
        const Result$ = await Fetch$.json();
        
        expect(Result$.status).toBe(HttpStatus.BadRequest);
        expect(Result$.error.text).toBe(`Header Field (${HeaderField}) missing in the request.`);
        expect(Result$.error.reference).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```

I would then have a single `*.spec.ts` file for each route, that would import this common test file, and somehow pass in the route information to be called.

The test file for each route, would have the Url (/rest/user, /rest/product/abc), as well as the method (post, get, delete, etc.) and would set any required headers for the particular route while the common code would unset a header and send the fetch request to verify the API returns an error.

I do not know how to do the import {} from 'transaction-common-headers' part of this, to get the describe, beforeEach, etc. working as part of my `delete-product.spec.ts` file.